# Setting DataContext for the root element in XAML without the property element syntax

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, datacontext

I was wondering if it's possible to write something like this:

```
<Window 
    ... xmlns definitions ...
    DataContext=<!--Create an instance here-->
></Window>
```

Instead of this:

```
<Window 
    ... xmlns definitions ...
>
   <Window.DataContext>
        <local:CustomViewModel />
   </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

I don't need workarounds to achieve the same effect, I'm just curious if the first kind of syntax is possible at all. I don't think that's the case but it's worth asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can see to this cleanly is to write your own [`MarkupExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.markupextension.aspx) that uses [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) (or your DI container) to create the VM, thus giving you a syntax like this:

```
<UserControl DataContext="{CreateNew local:CustomViewModel}"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about DataContext="{x:Static SomeClass.SomeProperty}" and then in SomeClass:

```
   public static object SomeProperty { get { return new object(); } }
```

Where object is the type you want to create. I am not sure if x:Static caches the object it once retrieved but if not, this would work. You could also try to sue [ObjectDataProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider_members.aspx) 
It allows you to call methods, constructors and properties.